# Unable to access nested data elements inside mutate

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, apply, purrr

I am trying to understand why the following code doesn't work. My understanding is it will take `data$Sepal.Length` (element within the nested data column) and iterate that one(the vector) over the function `sum`.

```
df <- iris %>%
    nest(-Species) %>%
    mutate(Total.Sepal.Length = map_dbl(data$Sepal.Length, sum, na.rm = TRUE))
print(df)
```

But this throws an error  `Total.Sepal.Length must be size 3 or 1, not 0.` The following code works by using anonymous function as how it is usually accessed

```
df <- iris %>%
    nest(-Species) %>%
    mutate(Total.Sepal.Length = map_dbl(data, function(x) sum(x$Sepal.Length, na.rm = TRUE)))
print(df)
```

I am trying to understand why the previous code didn't work even though I am correctly passing arguments to `mutate` and `map`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do this:

```
df <- iris %>%
  nest(-Species) %>%
  mutate(Total.Sepal.Length = map_dbl(data, ~sum(.x$Sepal.Length, na.rm = TRUE)))
```

Two things: any reason you're not using `group_by`?

Second: your initial mutate is trying to perform:

```
 map_dbl(df$data$Sepal.Length, sum, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Which brings an empty result, because `df$data$Total.Sepal.Length` is `NULL` (you have to access each list element to access the columns, so `df$data[[1]]$Total.Sepal.Length` works)

### Output:

```
# A tibble: 3 × 3
  Species    data              Total.Sepal.Length
  <fct>      <list>                         <dbl>
1 setosa     <tibble [50 × 4]>               250.
2 versicolor <tibble [50 × 4]>               297.
3 virginica  <tibble [50 × 4]>               329.
```

Comment: Thank @Juan Adding `group_by` doesn't make any difference right ? Here `iris %>% nest(-Species)` is same as `iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% nest( )`.

Can you please tell me how `mutate(Total.Sepal.Length = map_dbl(data$Sepal.Length, sum, na.rm = TRUE))` is accessing `df$data$Total.Sepal.Length` but `~sum(.x$Sepal.Length, na.rm = TRUE)` is not ?

`Total.Sepal.Length` is on left side of mutate right so it is referring to `df$Total.Sepal.Length` right (just like the how the output looks like)?

Comment: My idea with group_by was to perform something like `iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% summarise(Total.Sepal.Length = sum(Sepal.Length))`. Is there any reason you're working with lists of dataframes?

The reason the first doesn't work is because map is trying to access each element of df$data$Sepal.Length, but df$data$Sepal.Length is null, so it won't work. On the other side, the other map tries to access each element of df$data, and for each element access the `Sepal.Length` column and sum it